# keras: Multi-branch non-shared weight network input issues. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)

Tags: python, keras

I tried to write a Multi-branch network with non-shared weights using keras, but there was a problem with the input of the network. I expected the input shape to be `(None, 30, 64, 64, 3)`, but the input shape received by the network was `(None, None, None, None)`.

Each branch network is a VGG network.

```
def vggLstmNet():

inp = Input(shape=(flameSize, size, size, 3)) # (30,64,64,3)

x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(inp)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(x)

x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(x)

x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(x)

x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(x)

x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))(x)

x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)

return model
```

This is the fusion model.

```
class_models = Model(inputs=[input1.input, input2.input, input3.input, input4.input, input5.input, input6.input], outputs=x)
```

The location of the error is the input in each branch network. And the error information is as follows：

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_3'), name='input_3', description="created by layer 'input_3'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_4'), name='input_4', description="created by layer 'input_4'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_5'), name='input_5', description="created by layer 'input_5'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_6'), name='input_6', description="created by layer 'input_6'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 30, 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 30, 64, 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_7'), name='input_7', description="created by layer 'input_7'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).

ValueError: Input 0 of layer time_distributed_95 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
```

The input to the network is a data generator. Each time a `batchsize` list is generated, the list contains six elements, each of which is a shape of `(30, 64, 64, 3)` array.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your data generator must provide a list of 6 tensors of shape (batch_size, 30, 64, 64, 3)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. For multi-input networks, when using the generator, the generator should strictly return a tuple, and each element in the tuple corresponds to the input of the network one by one.

The generator returns：

```
yield {'in1': t1, 'in2': t2, 'in3': t3, 'in4': t4, 'in5': t5, 'in6': t6}, {'out': labels}
```

model：

```
class_models = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5, inp6], outputs=x)
```